# Confusion on the meaning of quotient.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

The following is an exercise in *Abstract Algebra.
An Introduction*, 3rd Edition, Thomas W. Hungerford.

> Let $a$ be any integer and let $b$ and $c$ be positive integers. Suppose that when $a$ is divided by $b$, the quotient is q and the remainder is $r$, so that
> $$a=bq+r, 0\le r < b.$$
> Suppose that when $q$ is divided by $c$, the
> quotient is $k$. Prove that when $a$ is divided by $bc$, then the quotient is also $k$.

I was unable to solve this problem. When I checked the solution manual, it started as follows:

> When $q$ is divided by $c$, the quotient is $k$, so that $q = ck$.

Is that implication correct? Why is it assumed that the remainder is 0 when $q$ is divided by $c$? Is it because the remainder was not mentioned? Am I missing something or is the author being sloppy here?

Comment: Assume $q=ck+s$. Then $a=b(ck+s)+r=bck+bs+r$, so when $a$ is divided by $bc$ the quotient is still $k$.

Comment: @tmaj The problem here is that you can not guarantee that $bs + r < bc$. If you can, please provide it as an answer, because that is what I failed to do.

Comment: After reading the problem statement more carefully, I'm inclined to think that when the author says "when $q$ is divided by $c$, the quotient is $k$", he means $c\mid q$, i.e. $c$ is a divisor of $q$, hence there is no remainder.